# How can I use LSTM in pytorch for classification?

Tags: pytorch

My code is as below:

```
class Mymodel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, num_layers, batch_size):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.proj = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.hidden = self.init_hidden()


    def init_hidden(self):
        return (Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size)),
                Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size)))

    def forward(self, x):
        lstm_out, self.hidden = self.lstm(x, self.hidden)
        output = self.proj(lstm_out)
        result = F.sigmoid(output)
        return result
```

I want to use LSTM to classify a sentence to good (1) or bad (0). Using this code, I get the result which is time_step * batch_size * 1 but not 0 or 1. How to edit the code in order to get the classification result?

Comment: Do you know how to solve this problem?@nnnmmm I found may be avg pool can help but I don't know how to use it in this code?

Answer (score 10):

### Theory:

Recall that an LSTM outputs a vector for every input in the series. You are using sentences, which are a series of words (probably converted to indices and then embedded as vectors). This code from the LSTM [PyTorch tutorial](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/sequence_models_tutorial.html#lstm-s-in-pytorch) makes clear exactly what I mean (***emphasis mine):

```
lstm = nn.LSTM(3, 3)  # Input dim is 3, output dim is 3
inputs = [autograd.Variable(torch.randn((1, 3)))
          for _ in range(5)]  # make a sequence of length 5

# initialize the hidden state.
hidden = (autograd.Variable(torch.randn(1, 1, 3)),
          autograd.Variable(torch.randn((1, 1, 3))))
for i in inputs:
    # Step through the sequence one element at a time.
    # after each step, hidden contains the hidden state.
    out, hidden = lstm(i.view(1, 1, -1), hidden)

# alternatively, we can do the entire sequence all at once.
# the first value returned by LSTM is all of the hidden states throughout
# the sequence. the second is just the most recent hidden state
# *** (compare the last slice of "out" with "hidden" below, they are the same)
# The reason for this is that:
# "out" will give you access to all hidden states in the sequence
# "hidden" will allow you to continue the sequence and backpropagate,
# by passing it as an argument  to the lstm at a later time
# Add the extra 2nd dimension
inputs = torch.cat(inputs).view(len(inputs), 1, -1)
hidden = (autograd.Variable(torch.randn(1, 1, 3)), autograd.Variable(
torch.randn((1, 1, 3))))  # clean out hidden state
out, hidden = lstm(inputs, hidden)
print(out)
print(hidden)
```

One more time: **compare the last slice of "out" with "hidden" below, they are the same**. *Why? Well...*

If you're familiar with LSTM's, I'd recommend the PyTorch LSTM [docs](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.LSTM) at this point. Under the output section, notice *h_t* is output at every *t*.

Now if you aren't used to LSTM-style equations, take a look at Chris Olah's [LSTM blog post](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/). Scroll down to the diagram of the unrolled network:

[image: Credit C Olah, "Understanding LSTM Networks"]

As you feed your sentence in word-by-word (`x_i`-by-`x_i+1`), you get an output from each timestep. You want to interpret the entire sentence to classify it. So you must wait until the LSTM has seen all the words. That is, you need to take `h_t` where `t` is the number of words in your sentence.

### Code:

Here's a coding [reference](https://github.com/yuchenlin/lstm_sentence_classifier). I'm not going to copy-paste the entire thing, just the relevant parts. The magic happens at `self.hidden2label(lstm_out[-1])`

```
class LSTMClassifier(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, vocab_size, label_size, batch_size):
        ...
        self.word_embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.hidden2label = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, label_size)
        self.hidden = self.init_hidden()

    def init_hidden(self):
        return (autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim)),
                autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim)))

    def forward(self, sentence):
        embeds = self.word_embeddings(sentence)
        x = embeds.view(len(sentence), self.batch_size , -1)
        lstm_out, self.hidden = self.lstm(x, self.hidden)
        y  = self.hidden2label(lstm_out[-1])
        log_probs = F.log_softmax(y)
        return log_probs
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be : `y  = self.hidden2label(self.hidden[-1])

Comment: @RameshK ``lstm_out`` is the hidden states from each time step. ``lstm_out[-1]`` is the final hidden state. ``self.hidden`` is a 2-tuple of the final hidden and cell vectors ``(h_f, c_f)``. Neglecting any necessary reshaping you could use ``self.hidden[0]``. There's nuances involved with masking and bidirectionality so usually I'd say ``self.hidden[0]`` is preferred but here it really doesn't matter.

Comment: thank you, but still not sure. The pytorch document says :
`- **h_n** of shape `(num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size)`: tensor
          containing the hidden state for `t = seq_len`.`
where the output is `Outputs: output, (h_n, c_n)`

Comment: How would I modify this to be used in a non-nlp setting? I have time series data for a pulse (a series of vectors) and want to categorise a sequence of vectors to 1 or 0? Embedding_dim would simply be input dim?

Comment: @donkey probably should be its own question, but you could remove the word embedding and feed your data into ``self.lstm`` directly, ensuring it has the same shape as x does: ``(sequence length, batch size, vector dimension)``

Comment: I am a little confused that if in **LSTM binary classification**, is there a way to use `sigmoid` function to get a prediction. Cause we know that there are differences between `sigmoid` and `softmax`, even when the label's size is 2. And `sigmoid` function is a element-wise activation function.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you need to figure out is the in which dim place you should put your batch size when you prepare your data. As far as I know, if you didn't set it in your nn.LSTM() init function, it will automatically assume that the second dim is your batch size, which is quite different compared to other DNN framework. Maybe you can try:

```
self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
```

like this to ask your model to treat your first dim as the batch dim.

Answer (score 0):

As a last layer you have to have a linear layer for however many classes you want i.e 10 if you are doing digit classification as in MNIST . For your case since you are doing a yes/no (1/0) classification you have two lablels/ classes so you linear layer has two classes. I suggest adding a linear layer as

nn.Linear ( feature_size_from_previous_layer , 2)

and then train the model using a cross-entropy loss.

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

Comment: But my code already has a linear layer. The problem is when the program runs on this line ' output = self.proj(lstm_out) ', there is an error message about the mismatch demension that I mentioned before.@Manoj Acharya

Comment: you probably have to reshape to the correct dimension . Use .view method for the tensors.