# How can I use an LSTM to classify a series of vectors into two categories in Pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, classification, lstm

I have a series of vectors representing a signal over time. I'd like to classify parts of the signal into two categories: 1 or 0. The reason for using LSTM is that I believe the network will need knowledge of the entire signal to classify.

My problem is developing the PyTorch model. Below is the class I've come up with.

```
class LSTMClassifier(nn.Module):

   def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, label_size, batch_size):
       self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_dim, hidden_dim)
       self.hidden2label = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, label_size)
       self.hidden = self.init_hidden()

   def init_hidden(self):
       return (torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim), 
               torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim))

   def forward(self, x):
       lstm_out, self.hidden = self.lstm(x, self.hidden)
       y  = self.hidden2label(lstm_out[-1])
       log_probs = F.log_softmax(y)
       return log_probs
```

However this model is giving a bunch of shape errors, and I'm having trouble understanding everything going on.  I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952930/how-can-i-use-lstm-in-pytorch-for-classification) SO question first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should follow [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html), especially `inputs` and `outputs` part, **always**.

This is how the classifier should look like:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class LSTMClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, label_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_dim, hidden_dim, batch_first=True)
        self.hidden2label = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, label_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        _, (h_n, _) = self.lstm(x)
        return self.hidden2label(h_n.reshape(x.shape[0], -1))


clf = LSTMClassifier(100, 200, 1)
inputs = torch.randn(64, 10, 100)
clf(inputs)
```

Points to consider:

- always use `super().__init__()` as it registers modules in your neural networks, allows for hooks etc.
- Use `batch_first=True` so you can pass inputs of shape `(batch, timesteps, n_features)`
- No need to `init_hidden` with `zeros`, it is the default value if left uninitialized
- No need to pass `self.hidden` each time to LSTM. Moreover, **you should not do that**. It means that elements from each batch of data are somehow next steps, while batch elements should be disjoint and you probably do not need that.
- `_, (h_n, _)` returns last hidden cell from last timestep, exactly of shape: `(num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size)`. In our case `num_layers` and `num_directions` is `1` so we get `(1, batch, hidden_size)` tensor as output
- Reshape to `(batch, hidden_size)` so it can be passed through linear layer
- Return logits without activation. Only one if it is a binary case. Use [`torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html) as loss for binary case and [`torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) for multiclass case. Also `sigmoid` is proper activation for binary case, while `softmax` or `log_softmax` is appropriate for multiclass.
- For binary only one output is needed. Any value below `0` (if returning unnormalized probabilities as in this case) is considered negative, anything above positive.